# Are "whole purpose" and "only purpose" synonymous?

Tags: synonyms, spoken-english, parts-of-speech

Are the phrases *whole purpose* and *only purpose* synonyms in this sentence (which you would say about/at your work):

> I am officeist. My whole purpose is my office.

It's part of speech.

Comment: *Officeist* is nifty, but I've never encountered it before. I'd be inclined to spell it without the ‹e›.

Comment: Yeah, I have no clue what you mean by "officeist"... like a "[workaholic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workaholic)"?

Comment: Officeist - somebody who discriminates based on whether another person works in/loves/is an office?

Comment: "Office worker" might be a more recognizable substitute for "officeist" . Or, to describe an avid, fanatical, driven, or obsessive office worker: "workaholic"

Comment: No no. It's like environmentalist. It means somebody who cares about office only. It's irony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a 'whole' is 100% of something, then yes, they are technically synonymous. After all, if 100% of your purpose is the office, then a) it is the only purpose you have, and b) you need a holiday.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the debatable 'officeist' from the structure for now & replacing it with the more common 'workaholic', I'd go for a third alternative, more idiomatic...

> "I'm a workaholic. My sole purpose in life is work"

'Sole' in this instance being meaning 1 at [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sole_1?q=sole) -
*only; single

the sole surviving member of the family

My sole reason for coming here was to see you.

This is the sole means of access to the building.*